# Django, url not found 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[Project Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyepY.png)

I am new to django. I am trying to create a simple rest api end point, but I get a 404. I am sure I am missing some setting.
models.py

```
class DisplayItems(models.Model):
    yesNo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    yogaMessage = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    yogaTimeMessage = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, yesNo, yogaMessage, yogaTimeMessage):
        displayItems = cls(yesNo=yesNo, yogaMessage=yogaMessage, yogaTimeMessage=yogaTimeMessage)
        return displayItems
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import DisplayItems

class DisplayItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    yesNo = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    yogaMessage = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    yogaTimeMessage = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = DisplayItems
        fields = ('__all__')
```

urls.py

```
from .views import DisplayItemsViews
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path(r'^zzz/', DisplayItemsViews.as_view()),
]
```

views.py

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import DisplayItemsSerializer
from .models import DisplayItems


class DisplayItemsViews(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        displayItems = DisplayItems.create("YES!", "There's yoga today", "At 2:00 pm Eastern Time")
        serializer = DisplayItemsSerializer(displayItems)
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

The url I am trying to run is http://127.0.0.1:8000/zzz/

I have read almost all relevant stackoverflow posts, but can't seem to understand what I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

1 - Have you installed `rest_framework` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` of your `settings.py`?

2 - Your `path()` in your `urls.py` should not contain the `r'^` portion, meaning the proper paths are `path('admin/', admin.site.urls)` and `path('zzz/', DisplayItemsViews.as_view())`.  This is old behavior from when Django suggested using `url()` instead of `path()`

3 - I assume you've imported `APIView` in your `views.py`, if not, you need to `from rest_framework.views import APIView`

EDIT:  My working local version.

**views.py**

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializers import DisplayItemsSerializer
from .models import DisplayItems


class DisplayItemsViews(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        displayItems = DisplayItems.create("YES!", "There's yoga today", "At 2:00 pm Eastern Time")
        serializer = DisplayItemsSerializer(displayItems)
        return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**settings.py**

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
    'rest_framework'
]
```

**urls.py**

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from base.views import DisplayItemsViews

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('zzz/', DisplayItemsViews.as_view())

]
```

**models.py**

```py
class DisplayItems(models.Model):
    yesNo = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    yogaMessage = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    yogaTimeMessage = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, yesNo, yogaMessage, yogaTimeMessage):
        displayItems = cls(yesNo=yesNo, yogaMessage=yogaMessage, yogaTimeMessage=yogaTimeMessage)
        return displayItems
```

**serializers.py**

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import DisplayItems

class DisplayItemsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    yesNo = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    yogaMessage = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    yogaTimeMessage = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = DisplayItems
        fields = ('__all__')
```

And the result, at localhost:8080/zzz
[image: Image of DRF]

Comment: Thanks Joe for your response
1. yes I do have the right settings.py

2. I tried with and without. I have removed them now.

3. Yes, I do have that import. Not sure, why I didn't put it in the code section

Still 404

Comment: Hmm, I recreated a barebones solution using your code and am able to get the expected result from that endpoint.  I'll update my answer with my full code so you can see if anything stands out.

Comment: @zebabasu I updated my answer.  But looking at your project structure, it seems like you're missing an app.  Did you do `manage.py startapp app_name`?  The views/models/etc should be in an app folder, not in your project folder.

Comment: wow ! that's working as is ! I am assuming you have the same folder structure as me ?
I am using Postman to test.

Comment: I didn't do that, but I have to do this in settings.py for it to compile
```INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'laz_yoga'
]
```

Comment: Here, you would want to do `python manage.py startapp laz_yoga` which will create a folder/app called `laz_yoga`, which is where your models.py, serializers.py, and views.py should live

Comment: I redid my project all over again and that worked ! thank you

Comment: @zeba basu mark this answer as accepted.